# Idle Notification not showing - Vaadin 14

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

I'm trying to use an add-on https://vaadin.com/directory/component/idle-notification for Session Management. I would like to show notification when user is inactive in the application for a given time.

I have Main Layout:

```
@PWA(name = "App", shortName = "App", enableInstallPrompt = false)
@Theme(themeFolder = "app")
@CssImport(value = "./styles/example.css", themeFor = "vaadin-grid")
@PreserveOnRefresh
@Push
public class MainView extends AppLayout implements AfterNavigationObserver {

    public MainView() {
         ...
         
         IdleNotification idleNotification = new IdleNotification();
         idleNotification.setSecondsBeforeNotification(90);
         idleNotification.setMessage("Your session will expire in " +  
                                   IdleNotification.MessageFormatting.SECS_TO_TIMEOUT  
         + " seconds.");
         idleNotification.addExtendSessionButton("Extend session");
         idleNotification.addRedirectButton("Logout now", "logout");
         idleNotification.addCloseButton();
         idleNotification.setExtendSessionOnOutsideClick(false);

         UI.getCurrent().add(idleNotification);
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly notification not showing.
I also tried set parameters in application.properties as:

```
vaadin.closeIdleSessions=false
vaadin.heartbeatInterval=true
vaadin.pushMode=true
```

but that does not solve the problem

Comment: Two things. One, I think you should set `closeIdleSessions` to true. Second, you should specify a number for `heartbeatInterval` (like `vaadin.heartbeat.interval=300`).

Comment: @TarekOraby thank you for response. Unfortunatelly it didn't help :(. I also set server.servlet.session.timeout=2m . Then after 2 minutes, the application redirects to the login page, but notification not showing.

Comment: Actually, you would also need to set the max inactive interval via `VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(95);`. Just tested the component with Vaadin 14.8.13, and it works for me.

Comment: @TarekOraby Can I have a code please? Where are you setting `VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(95);`?

Comment: I have 14.8.1 Vaadin version.

Comment: You can set it in any view. Or better you can use a SessionInitListener as described here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-ui-init-listener.

Comment: Basically you should do. ```import com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceInitEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServiceInitListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ServiceListener implements VaadinServiceInitListener {
    @Override
    public void serviceInit(ServiceInitEvent event) {
        event.getSource().addSessionInitListener(
                initEvent -> initEvent.getSession().getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(95));
    }
}```

Comment: @TarekOraby 
I did it. Did not help.
Anything else I should check? Or is there any other way to get a notification asking to extend it before it expires?

Comment: Do you have a whitelisted or blacklisted packages in your application.properties?

Comment: @TarekOraby Yes, I have property:
`vaadin.whitelisted-packages=com.my.app` - main package of my app.

Comment: @TarekOraby I added com.vaadin.componentfactory to vaadin.whitelisted-packages and work!!! thank you!

Comment: @TarekOraby Can I change the notation styles, e.g. width?

Comment: Can you please add your solution as the answer? StackOverflow is not a discussion forum

Answer (score 0):

The problem was setting vaadin.whitelisted-packages = com.my.app, I added com.vaadin.componentfactory to vaadin.whitelisted-packages and work.